# How to get std::string or char[] from filesystem?

Tags: c++

I have a loop that run through the whole directory I need to get a path from each file in order to use it.

This is my method

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

for (const auto & entry : fs::directory_iterator(sourceDir))
{
    if (fs::is_directory(entry))
        continue;
    StreamRAII iStream{ entry, StreamMode::READ_BINARY };
}
```

issue is that `StreamRAII` constructor have to get `std::string` as its first parameter

```
StreamRAII(const std::string& filename, const char *mode);
```

But this `const auto & entry : fs::directory_iterator(sourceDir)`, `entry` is `derectory_entry` type.

Question is,  how to get path to my file? How to convert `derectory_entry` to `std::string` or `char[]`?

**P.S.** when I use `cout` I can see this path to my files...

Comment: Very likely one achieves this by using `std::filesystem::path` ... As for the issue with using this completely unknown thing `StreamRAII`, that you just calmly drop into your question, I might paste the relevant sentence from documentation of path: "... Paths are implicitly convertible to and from `std::basic_strings`, which makes it possible to use them with over files APIs, e.g. as an argument to std::ifstream::open..."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`derectory_entry`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry) has a [`path()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry/path) function that returns a [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) that holds the path name of the file.  You can use it's [`string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string) function to get a `std::string` from that path.  That would make your code look like

```
StreamRAII iStream{ entry.path().string(), StreamMode::READ_BINARY };
```

Comment: "... Paths are implicitly convertible to and from std::basic_strings, which makes it possible to use them with over files APIs, e.g. as an argument to std::ifstream::open..."

Comment: @ChefGladiator Where are you quoting that from?  `std::filesystem::path` has no `operator std::string()` so that can't be right.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path  ---- https://snag.gy/0hJEaD.jpg

Comment: @ChefGladiator This is bizarre.  cppreference states that, but I see no way how it does that, and at least MSVS doesn't have an implicit conversion.  I'm going to ask a Q to get it figured out.

Comment: Probably, but g++ compiles it as a such, please see my answer bellow.

Comment: @ChefGladiator It does not compile on MSVS, so I'm not sure which compiler is right.

Comment: Ah I understand .. MSVS stands for MS Visual Studio ... which uses MSVC aka MS Visual C++ which is actually Microsoft's compiler CL aka cl.exe ... hugh ... I was wondering what is "MSVS" ... ok let me jump to this i5 WIN PRo machines with the latest VS2019 on it and try ... thanks for pointing this out ...

Comment: @ChefGladiator: That's not how it works - [`fstream` itself takes a `std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream). It's unspecified whether it internally converts a string to a path, a path to a string, or something else.

Comment: I can report that also compiles using up-to-date VisualStudio 2019 Community Edition.  The only project setup, I have changed is to add `/std:c++17`.
Compiler installed on this i5 WIN10 PRO machine is:
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.22.27905 for x86 --- Let  me add the mockup for `StreamRAII` that will have the constructor as described by OP

Comment: @NathanOliver, ah well (and yes) does not compile under VS2019 (latest and updated) ... Can we take the cppreference and g++ as the authorities on this one?

Comment: @ChefGladiator Already done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57377349/implicit-conversion-between-stdfilesystempath-and-stdstring-should-it-hap).  Both compilers are right.  On windows it will convert to a `std::wstring` and on POSIX it will convert to a `std::string`

Comment: I remember vaguely about this ... "design feature" ... -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/file-system-navigation?view=vs-2019 --- although now here is this sentence -- "A path object is implicitly convertible to std::wstring or std::string. " .. and indeed VS2019 does it if I cast to std::string reference ... ugh , I doubt this is elegant ..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have to path from a file, use the `.path()` method of the `directory_iterator` class.
If you want to get a string from this path, just use the `.string()` method on your path object.

Comment: "... Paths are implicitly convertible to and from std::basic_strings, which makes it possible to use them with over files APIs, e.g. as an argument to std::ifstream::open..."

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue what is `StreamRAII` that everybody here seems to know about. Here is the [standard C++ code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/e9Bg8p1dHe6IW5ad) that probably induces the inspiration into the direction of the right answer of the OP  question.

```
// $ g++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>

struct StreamRAII final {
  StreamRAII(const std::string& filename, const char *mode)
 {
  using namespace std;
   cout << "\n\nInside StreamRAII(const std::string& filename, const char 
  *mode)\n\nFilename: "  << filename.c_str() << "\n\nmode: " << mode ;
}
};

int main()
{
  namespace fs = std::filesystem;

  for (const auto & entry : fs::directory_iterator("."))
  {
    if (fs::is_directory(entry))
       continue;
     StreamRAII iStream{ entry.path(), "StreamMode::READ_BINARY" };
  }

  return 0 ;   
 }
```

looking into the cppreference (en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path ---- snag.gy/0hJEaD.jpg) and using g++ this works fine ... but as of today latest and updated VS2019 does not compile the code above.

Comment: No, you have to use `.path().string()`, otherwise you get the error type mismatch

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko only under MSVC (the latest and updated) but not under g++ ... see the link to the wandbox please -- https://wandbox.org/permlink/e9Bg8p1dHe6IW5ad

Comment: So shouldn't you use `.path().string()` to be portable?

Comment: @NathanOliver please see here https://godbolt.org/z/Pr9Und -- due to MSVC I had to do it that way ... implicit transformation to `std::string` indeed exist in MSVC case, but needs a bit of convincing ...

Comment: @ChefGladiator I'm 99.9999999% certain that code is UB.  `p1` is implicitly convertible to a `std::wstring` on windows.  That cast to a `std::string` is going to violate the strict aliasing rules.

Comment: @NathanOliver , I 99.9999999% agree. Still, both g++ and clang have no issues whatsoever and need no "toxic casting".  I consider this issue closed. Thanks for watching, everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

To make this platform independent with C++17, you must ensure that `StreamRAII` either accepts a `std::filesystem::path` or that the contract for the `std::string` input is that it must be UTF-8-encoded, then you must use it in this way and it won't perform any conversion on typical POSIX-systems (but perhaps on others (such as MSVC)). It won't work with C++20 though

```
StreamRAII iStream{ entry.path().u8string(), StreamMode::READ_BINARY };
```

If you have no control over `StreamRAII` you can only convert the path to a `std::string` (as other stated) and keep your fingers crossed that it will work anyway. This will compile with C++20 but if it works or not is (probably) system dependent

```
StreamRAII iStream{ entry.path().string(), StreamMode::READ_BINARY };
```