# Implicit conversion between std::filesystem::path and std::string, should it happen?

Tags: c++, path, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion, std-filesystem

The cppreference page for [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) states:

> Paths are implicitly convertible to and from `std::basic_strings`, which makes it possible to use them with over files APIs, e.g. as an argument to `std::ifstream::open`

Now the conversion to a `std::filesystem::path` is easy to see as it has a non-explicit constructor that takes `std::string` types. What I can't seem to find, though, is a way to go to a `std::string` implicitly.

There is a `string` function, but it is `std::string string() const;`, not `operator std::string()`. Using

```
#include <filesystem>

void foo(std::string) {}

int main()
{
    namespace fs = std::filesystem;
    fs::path p1;
    foo(p1);
}
```

this code compiles fine with [icc](https://godbolt.org/z/WdJV3K), [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/PhtSx2), and [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/PPv0wq), but not with [MSVS](https://godbolt.org/z/kVsnS4), where it gives the error:

```
example.cpp

<source>(10): error C2664: 'void foo(std::string)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::filesystem::path' to 'std::string'

<source>(10): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Compiler returned: 2
```

So, which compiler is right? Is there an implicit conversion sequence, or are the compilers just being helpful?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an implicit conversion to `std::basic_string<value_type>`, where `value_type` is an OS-dependent character type.

And, *(§30.10.8 in my draft copy, n4659)*

> For POSIX-based operating systems, value_type is `char`  [...]
>   For Windows-based operating systems, value_type is `wchar_t` [...]

so there doesn't need to be an implicit conversion to `std::string` on Windows, only to `std::wstring`.

Answer (score 6):

All compilers are right. It is [specified by the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/fs.class.path#fs.path.native.obs-4) that it should have a conversion to `string_type`:

> ```
> operator string_type() const;
> ```
>
> Returns: `native()`.

`string_type` here is:

```
using string_type = basic_string<value_type>;
```

And `native()` :

> ```
> const string_type& native() const noexcept;
> ```
>
> Returns: The pathname in the native format.

Native format being `basic_string<value_type>`.

`value_type` however doesn't have to be `char` and thus the conversion to `std::string` doesn't always exist. It's only mandated that one to `basic_string<>`exists.