# How can I erase first and last character in string?

Tags: c++, c++17, std-filesystem

This function returns an array of strings with a list of files in a folder. It looks like this:

`"folder//xyz.txt"`

How can I make it look like this?

`folder//xyz.txt`

Its the same but without `""`.

```
vector<string> list_of_files(string folder_name)                           
{
    vector<string> files;
    string path = folder_name;

    for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(path))      
    { 
        stringstream ss;
        ss << entry.path();        //convert entry.path() to string
        string str = ss.str();                  
                    
        files.push_back(ss.str());
    }  

    return files;
}
```

Comment: The quotes are how you delimit string literals, but they're almost certainly not actually in the string. Where do you get the idea there are actual quotes in the string's data?

Comment: Why are you using `std::stringstream` in this manner?  Just use `string str = entry.path();` instead, as [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) has a [conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/native) to `std::string` (which you are invoking when constructing the `stringstream`).

Comment: You can use a `trim()`function like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring/25385766#25385766

Comment: The quotes are coming from the `<<` operator. [`operator <<(std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_ltltgtgt) says: **std::quoted is used so that spaces do not cause truncation when later read by stream input operator.**

Comment: @KubaWójcik See my answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Actually, it's a conversion operator to `std::basic_string<value_type>`, which is not necessarily (and, on Windows, is not) `std::string`. ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57377349/4386278))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erasing the first and last characters of a string is easy:

```
if (str.size() >= 1)
   str.erase(0, 1);   // from 1st char (#0), len 1; bit verbose as not designed for this

if (str.size() >= 1)
   str.pop_back();    // chop off the end
```

Your quotes have come from inserting the path to a stream ([`quoted` is used to help prevent bugs due to spaces down the line](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_ltltgtgt)).

Fortunately, you don't need any of this: as explored in the comments, the stringstream is entirely unnecessary; the path already converts to a string if you ask it to:

```
vector<string> list_of_files(string folder_name)
{
    vector<string> files;

    for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(folder_name))
        files.push_back(entry.path().string());

    return files;
}
```

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it currently. But this looks like such a good application of C++20 ranges, where `list_of_files` could be a one liner with a `ranges::views::transform` on `fs::directory_iterator` to compute `.path()` o each element. Until you actually try to do it and stumble on the current complication of converting the range to a `std::vector`. I guess let's have hope for C++23.

Comment: Im getting 2 errors when im not using stringstream https://imgur.com/a/NmcV2st

Comment: @KubaWójcik The implicit conversion should have been enough, but try it with `.string()` to be clear. Probably a VS thing.

Comment: @darcamo Dunno, a simple for loop is much simpler and easier to read than all of that complicated stuff.

Comment: @KubaWójcik Ah, my mistake, it was because the implicit conversion is actually to the _"native"_ string type, which for Windows is `wstring`, not `string.  ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57377349/4386278))

Comment: @KubaWójcik Note that this may be important, if you have paths with non-ASCII characters in them. Consider having a vector of something else, or performing a conversion to UTF-8.

Comment: The result of `path().string()` on Windows is unspecified: "*Otherwise, if `path::value_type` is `wchar_t`, **conversion, if any, is unspecified**. This is the case on Windows, where `wchar_t` is 16 bit and the native encoding is UTF-16.*"  So yes, a `vector<wstring>` would be a better choice in that case, and then you can use `path().wstring()` instead of `path().string()`.  Or, why not just use a `vector<path>` instead, and do all processing on `path`s as much as possible? Don't convert `path`s to `string`s unless you need to interact with platform APIs that require file path strings.

Comment: ^ Yes, do that.